# Adding vectors to empty JcomboBox

Tags: vector, jcombobox, visible

I am working on a program that integrates with mysql.

I am querying the database and using a vector to populate a JcomboBox with the results . This is done as the GUI gets built and is working fine.
Based on the item chosen in the first JcomboBox I want to popultate the second JcomboBox.
I am using an action listener on the first JcomboBox, calling another class, passing the item selected in the first box, doing the query and returning the result as a vector.

As I used a vector in the first case I thought I could just call

```
box2.addItem(vector2);
```

My problem is that I get the result of the query as one entry enclosed by []

I am puzzled because

```
JComboBox Box1 = new JComboBox(vector1);
```

works to set up a JcomboBox at intitialisation but I cannot add a vector to an empty box after it has been made visible.

I can input single lines using box2.addItem("new line etc");
but I want to add a vector line in box 1.

Could someone give me a hint as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that should be add the vector result to box 2.

The result contains about 9 values but are all added as one line in box 2.

I need the resulting vector to give me the 9 or so values in separate lines.

Thanks guys!